# How can I set up paths for reading input from a file in check unit test?

Tags: c, unit-testing, makefile, autotools

I am learning to use check for unit testing my code. I have my project set up with autotools, and I have check set up to do some tests.

The program I'm making is a red black tree that I want to be able to use for other projects. For one of my tests, I want to read input from a file to use as test data to insert into the tree. I have a file called words.txt in my tests directory that I want to read from. I like to keep my build tree separate though. So how can set up my makefiles to put the words file in the right place? Then can I just read it from the directory that make check runs in?

Here's what everything looks like:

> Project Directory:

```
├── aclocal.m4
├── autom4te.cache
│   ├── output.0
│   ├── output.1
│   ├── requests
│   ├── traces.0
│   └── traces.1
├── build-aux
│   ├── ar-lib
│   ├── compile
│   ├── depcomp
│   ├── install-sh
│   ├── missing
│   └── test-driver
├── config.h.in
├── config.h.in~
├── configure
├── configure.ac
├── Makefile.am
├── Makefile.in
├── src
│   ├── libredblack.c
│   ├── libredblack.h
│   ├── main.c
│   ├── Makefile.am
│   └── Makefile.in
└── tests
    ├── check_libredblack.c
    ├── Makefile.am
    ├── Makefile.in
    └── words.txt
```

> tests/Makefile.am:

```
TESTS = check_libredblack
check_PROGRAMS = check_libredblack
check_libredblack_SOURCES = check_libredblack.c $(top_builddir)/src/libredblack.h
check_libredblack_CFLAGS = @CHECK_CFLAGS@
check_libredblack_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/src/libredblack.a @CHECK_LIBS@
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to let the Makefile tell the test program where to find it.

Add to your test program's `CPPFLAGS` something like `-DWORDS_LOCATION="\"$(top_srcdir)/tests/data/words.txt\""` and then the path to the data file will be available to your program as a string, defined in the macro `WORDS_LOCATION`.